# Context Provider returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to create a context that should return an object named feedback

- i can see the state being updated in the component tree within the provider
- but when i'm trying to access it using Context Hook ,i'm getting undefined

FeedbackContext.jsx

```
import FeedbackData from '../data/FeedbackData'
import { createContext, useState } from 'react'

const FeedackContext = createContext()

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
export const FeedbackProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState(FeedbackData)
    return (
        <FeedackContext.Provider value={{ feedback }}>{children}</FeedackContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default FeedackContext
```

App.jsx

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import FeedackContext, { FeedbackProvider } from './context/FeedbackContext'

function App() {
    const feedback = useContext(FeedackContext)
    console.log(typeof feedback)
    return (
        <FeedbackProvider>
            <>
                <div>{feedback}</div>
            </>
        </FeedbackProvider>
    )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 3):

`const feedback = useContext(FeedackContext)` should be used in the descendant component of the `FeedbackProvider` component.

E.g.

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import FeedackContext, { FeedbackProvider } from './context/FeedbackContext'

const Child = () => {
    const feedback = useContext(FeedackContext)
    console.log(typeof feedback);
    return <div>{feedback}</div>
}

function App() {
    return (
        <FeedbackProvider>
            <Child/>
        </FeedbackProvider>
    )
}
```